# Mockito invalid args for namedparameterjdbctemplate

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

```
@Test
public void testGetScheduleTotalCount() {       

     when(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyMap(),Mockito.eq(Integer.class))).thenReturn(2);
}
```

While running above test I am getting below error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
>   Invalid use of argument matchers! 3 matchers expected, 2 recorded:

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Try to add the real method signature, more detailed test case and possibly full stack trace

Comment: Please provide error message from your ide or the log. Ideally stacktrace

Comment: edited a question body with actual test and error

Comment: are you sure there is a version of queryForObject that accepts a Map? Can you add the actual method signature that you want to mock?

Comment: public Integer getScheduleTotalCount(String query, DataGridRequestDTO gridRequest) {
  Map<String, Object> namedParameters = new HashMap<>();

  return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, namedParameters, Integer.class);

 }

Comment: from spring boot jdbc docs  namedjdbctemplate which accepts a map              public <T> T queryForObject(String sql, Map<String, ?> paramMap, Class<T> requiredType)
   throws DataAccessException {

  return queryForObject(sql, paramMap, new SingleColumnRowMapper<>(requiredType));
 }

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(query, namedParameters, Integer.class);`, your set-up should be:

```
Mockito.doReturn(myInteger).when(jdbcTemplateMock).queryForObject(Mockito.anyString()
       , Mockito.any(Object[].class), Mockito.eq(Integer.class));
```

Regarding the `queryForObject(sql, paramMap, new SingleColumnRowMapper<>(requiredType));`, your set-up could be:

```
Mockito.doReturn(myInteger)
       .when(n)
       .queryForObject(Mockito.anyString()
           , ArgumentMatchers.<Map<Integer,?>>any()
           , ArgumentMatchers.<org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper<Integer>>any());
```

Comment: now It's giving compiling error actual namedparameters accept either Map or SqlparameterSource

Comment: no luck still facing Invalid use of argument matchers! 3 matchers expected, 2 recorded: